# ruby on rails after_update callback hooks issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-2

In my Rails Application, I have after_update callback. But this callback is executed when my record is first time created using save method and when it is updated using update_attributes.

So I want a way using which the callback/method must be called when it is coming to update method but currently it is getting executing when it is coming to create as well as update method.

I think update_attribute also call internally a save method, because of this issue is coming.

So is there any way using which I can call my hook when record is updated and not saved.

I found one way using attr_accessors but I wanted some other way as maintaining  these flags will be very difficult for my app

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
after_update do |model| 
  model.name = model.name.capitalize unless model.new_record?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`after_update` only gets called after a update of the model. For it to get called when a model is created, you must update its attributes after `.save` is called on the model. `.update_attribute` and `.update_attributes` is not the create of a model, it is actually updating the model. 
`.update_attribute` calls the `.save` method internally. `.save` is called to save the state of the model, new or updated. When you call it, ActiveRecord writes the new state to the database. When a model is created or updated, it is always done trough the `.save method`